# SQL Server Management Studio execute shortcut & keyboard shortcuts

Tags: sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

1. Is there any easy way to execute a chunk of code instead of moving cursor to the beginning of code chunk, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to the end of code, then hit <kbd>F5</kbd>?
2. Is there any keyboard shortcut to duplicate line (duplicate several lines), delete line (delete several lines)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. No, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is also "Execute" which is what I use which might be easier
2. No, but you may be able to find something in [all SSMS KB shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205(SQL.90).aspx) on MSDN. Example: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down arrows</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> x 2

Comment: I have been aware of CTRL+E since sql server 2000. I have happily used it in subsequent versions up to sql 2016. However, the other day it is no longer working on SQL 2014 ! i had to start using F5 instead. (some update must have removed it me thinks).

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. Global Execute shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [SSMS Tool Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) as it has some features around SQL snippets and execution.

Answer (score 1):

@Keyboard short cut to copy a line

<kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>  -- Note there is no need to select the line, use the shortcut with the cursor anywhere on the line & the whole line will be copied.

E.g. <kbd>CTL+C</kbd>, <kbd>CTL+V</kbd> --will copy the current line & paste it in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this... You can use Alt + X and it should work just as CTRL + E

Comment: How does this answer differ from the previous answers already posted here?